# Could not locate login item in the caller's bundle error when using SMLoginItemSetEnabled

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to get my swift Mac app to launch at login using the method described in this page: https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/

However, I keep getting the following errors as soon as I call SMLoginItemSetEnabled:

> Could not locate login item com.domain.LauncherApplication in the caller's bundle

> Could not enable login item: com.domain.LauncherApplication: 3: No such process

I checked that the launcher app ID is correct multiple times, I tried changing it and changing its version number. I even tried cleaning the project and moving the base app to /Applications but I always get these error messages.

Any idea what the problem might be? (Notice the solution must not require me to disable App Sandboxing)

Comment: Please double-check all steps again. A tiny mistake can ruin the entire functionality.

Comment: I checked all steps multiple times but I couldn't make it work - that's why I'm asking here for help. Unfortunately, that article wasn't always clear on how to do each step so it's possible I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the problem but it took a long time since it was so sneaky: In the Copy File Build Phase section I entered "Contents/Library/LoginItem" as the subpath instead of "Contents/Library/LoginItems" (notice the 's' in the end - can't believe I missed it). So thank you @vadian! You were absolutely right.